# Knockout tournament probability

Tags: probability

$P_1, P_2, P_3,\dots, P_8$ are 8 players of equal strength who play with each other in a knockout tournament. The probability that $P_1$ wins against $P_2$ and $P_3$ to reach final and also wins the tournament is $p$ then find $p$.

I am not getting how to start solving it, I tried is making different cases but it's going on lengthier, is there any short method to solve it?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: For the problem statement to make sense, I assume that the first round matches are assigned by (uniform9 random, i.e., the first round is *not* fixed to be P1 vs P2, P3 vs. P4, P5 vs P6, P7 vs P8

Comment: How is the setup? $P_1$ vs. $P_2$, $P_3$ vs. $P_4$, etc. and then winner of $P_1/P_2$ vs. winner of $P_3/P_4$ and so on?

Comment: The answer given is 1/168

Answer (score 2):

By symmetry, $P_1$ is the ultimate winner with probability $\frac 18$, and $P_1$ will defeat three other players on the way. If the first round is set up as $P_1$ vs $P_2$, $P_3$ vs. $P_4$, etc., and the winners are again paired from left to right, then it is already clear that $P_1$ won against $P_2$ in the first round. However, $P_1$ encountered either $P_3$ or $P_4$ in the second round (and one of $P_5,\ldots, P_8$ in the final), so $P_1$ won against $P_3$ only with the probability that $P_3$ reached the second round. The latter happens with probability $\frac12$. So in total, the conditions of the problem statement are met with probability $$\frac1{16}$$ because four independent events with probability $\frac12$ each must occur: $P_1$ wins first round, $P_3$ wins first round, $P_1$ wins second round, $P_1$ wins third round.

*But According to the comment about the desired answer, this is not the correct interpretation of the problem statement.*

---

On the other hand, if the first round is not assigned as above but rather in form of a uniformly random permutation, we have to argue differently: Still, $P_1$ is the ultimate winner with probability $\frac18$. The two opponents $P_1$ encountered on the way to the final (the problem statement says that $P_2,P_3$ are encounterd on the *way* to the final, not *in* the final), are a uniformly random 2-subset of the other seven players. As only one of these $7\choose 2$ subsets leads to the desired outcome, we arrive at a probability of
$$ \frac 18\cdot\frac1{7\choose 2}=\frac1{168}.$$

---

The same with a different approach: One fo $P_2,P_3$ must be the opponent of $P_1$ in the first round (probability $\frac 27$). $P_1$ must win the first round (probability $\frac12$) the other one of $P_2,P_3$ who did not meet $P_1$ in round one, must win their first round (probability $\frac12$) and then be the opponent of $P_1$ in the next round (probabiiuty $\frac 13$). Then $P_1$ must win again (probabiity $\frac12$) and then win the final (probabiity $\frac12$).
$$ \frac27\frac12\frac12\frac13\frac12\frac12=\frac1{168}.$$